# Timeline Area Type

Tags: python, scripting, timeline

Does anyone know why TIMELINE doesn't show up in [Area Type](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=bpy%20context%20area%20ui_type#bpy.types.Area.type)?

```
bpy.context.screen.areas[0].type = 'TIMELINE'
```

throws a TypeError. It is however available in the Editor Type popup:
[image]

I don't understand how the Dope Sheet works, but Timeline doesn't.

Comment: Also, as a note, you see it says "Shift F12" is the shortcut for it, but it isn't. Shift F12 opens the Dope Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check an area that's a Timeline to see what it's type is. It's `DOPESHEET_EDITOR`.

If you want to switch `area` to a Timeline, I think this works

```
area.type = 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR'
area.spaces[0].mode = 'TIMELINE'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm still confused though. So Timeline is some kind of mode inside of the Dope Sheet area type?

Comment: That's what it looks like.